# Exuberant Ctags produces "Unexpected end of file" error on empty *.ml file

Tags: exuberant-ctags

I found that Exuberant Ctags gives no output message on most empty files, except for `*.ml` files.

To reproduce, try following commands:

```
$ touch empty.txt empty.c empty.ml

$ ctags empty.txt

$ ctags empty.c

$ ctags empty.ml
ctags: Unexpected end of file: empty.ml
```

How can I make ctags behave consistently on all file types?

---

- macOS Mojave 10.14.2
- Exuberant Ctags 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed in Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io) .